# How do hide div if ad does not appear

Tags: html, adsense

I just implemented AdSense in my website. I've added a box-shadow to the div that contains my ad to add a level of depth. When there's no ad, or the ad is blocked using adblock or something, that div is empty and the box-shadow is just there and it looks stupid. How do I hide that div if no ad is shown or blocked? here's my code thus far:

```
<div id="footer">
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    ad stuff
    //-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

```
#footer { 
position: relative;
bottom:0;
width:728px;
height: 90px;
text-align: center;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: is the footer the id were the adsense is?

Comment: the ad is in the footer

Answer (score 0):

You can probably check the contents of that div (id: 'footer') after those scripts run with your own script in a third tag.  In the script you can check to see if the div has more content added to if, and if not you can remove the shadow.  You'll probably want to load the page with the ad and with it blocked and compare what shows up in the div to get an idea of what it looks like empty and what it looks like when shown.

Comment: I have ad block so I know what it looks like sans ad. thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

By default you can have it hidden, and load the ad using the jquery getScript method. Upon success you can make it visible.

```
$.getScript("http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    // make the ad visible
    $('#ad').show();
});
```

This will attempt to load the show_ad.js script, and upon success will invoke the callback function which would make the ad visible.

It all depends on how ad blockers work. If they simply prevent loading scripts at googlesyndication then this should work.

Comment: I'm actually not sure what the behavior would be if there is an adblocker.

Comment: do I need to ad anymore code to that function? I have almost no experience with jquery or javascript

Comment: i updated my response, but basically you would just need to change the selector from ```#ad``` to footer or wherever the ad is located.

Comment: out of curiosity, did this work? Or does the ad blocker allow the script to be loaded.

Comment: this does not appear to work. you could go through my source code if you'd like. [link](http://perrywaxman.com)

Comment: I looked at the page source and JScript.js is empty. You need to place the code above inside, change $('#ad') to $('.footer') and you have to remove the script tag that loads the show_ad.js.

Comment: Oh and the footer should be hidden by default.

Answer (score 0):

This javascript **removes** the div:

```
var el = document.getElementById("footer");
if (el.innerHTML == "") {el.parentNode.removeChild(el)};
```

But if it messes your layout you can just set styles for CSS that are "bothering you" and/or don't look good empty.
To **hide** it if empty:

```
addEvent(window, 'load', function(){
var el = document.getElementById("footer");
if (el.innerHTML == "") {el.style.display="none";}
});
```

Comment: was this what you were looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to implement this in my JS file. I started a jquery thing in it but I have no idea how to implement this, sorry! Like I said before, I am entirely new to JS and JQ

Comment: Do you want to hide it or remove it?

Comment: If you add my second code example it should work as it is, without any changes.